# how can I get a char*[] from python

Tags: python, c++, swig

I use swig wrapped some c++ api function.
There is one function, the interface is f(char*[] strs).

How can I pass a valid parameter to this function. 
This is what I did.

```
str = ["str","str2"]
f(str)
```

it will throw error

```
TypeError: in method 'f', argument 1 of type 'char *[]
```

Comment: check your `f function`, it takes the `char []` list and you given `list of string`. So call `f function` with `char list.`

Comment: @Odedra char* is a string in C. you can init a char* [] like this. char *list[] = {"str","str1"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWIG does not convert arrays to Python lists automatically. Since you are using C++, use std::string and std::vector for your `f`, then SWIG will make all the necessary conversions automatically (don't forget to include "std_vector.i" and such, see the SWIG docs):

```
void f(std::vector<std::string> > strs)
```

If you cannot modify the declaration of `f`, you can create an `%inline` wrapper in the .i:

```
%inline {
    void f(const std::vector<std::string> >& strs) 
    {
        // create tmpCharArray of type char*[] from strs
        const char* tmpCharArray[] = new const char* [strs.size()];
        for (i=0; i<strs.size(); i++) 
              tmpCharArray[i] = strs[i].c_str();
        f(tmpCharArray);
        delete[] tmpCharArray;
     }
}
```

Comment: Cool. Let me know if there is any improvement needed for you to upvote, and welcome to SO!

Comment: It is a good enough answer. I find  [something](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn59) cooler.  this way, I do not even have to write a wrapper, and char** can be used for all the functions which required.

Comment: Thanks for posting the link.